# Eclipse RCP menu bar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Currently I am working on an update from Eclipse 3 to Eclipse 4. In the new version I have a toolbar on the left, which is only visible in my intro part.

[image]

Where does this menubar come from? How can I disable it?

At first I thought it comes from the CustomizableIntroPart, but I have created my own IntroPart and the menu bar still is visible.

Comment: That is a minimized part stack, I don't know if it can be hidden.

Comment: If understand that component correct, all minimzed perspectives (?) are added here? Is it possible to close a perspective when switching to the intro part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component is a vertical TrimBar. I have disabled it via CSS using the following rule:

```
#org-eclipse-ui-trim-vertical1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```